# Count sum of the given html object's text using Angular 1.x.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tring to count sum of all the tds which has ng-model. But It works as a string as shown in the code below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 ng-app>
  <tr>
    <th>Products</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td ng-model="one">120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td ng-model="two">120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 3</td>
    <td ng-model="three">120</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{{ one + two + three }}
<div>
```

Comment: Did you declare your scope variables?

Comment: no. i don't.. @SterlingArcher

Comment: ´ng-model´ directive doesn't work with any kind of elements. Use it on an ´input´ tag.

Comment: what i need to use for other elements... i could not use input tag @nicooga

Comment: Inputs must work and are the normal way to go. They are one of the few types of elements that allow user input without a large ammount of hacking.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you can't use an input.

Comment: I have edited my question .. As i have table and it is from ajax so i need those value and show sum of it .. that why i do not use input tags

Comment: Show the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind`

#### and `ng-init`

```
<table border=1 ng-app ng-init="one = 120;two = 120;three = 120;">
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bwvdz9gr/)</kbd>

#### or  initialization in controller:

```
$scope.one = 120;
$scope.two = 120;
$scope.three = 120;
```

*HTML*

```
<table border=1 ng-app>
  <tr>
    <th>Products</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td ng-bind="one"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td ng-bind="two"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 3</td>
    <td ng-bind="three"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Result: 360

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/swuvo37c/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You should not use div for an input , you should use input element. Also if you are binding only in HTML multiply the value by 1 instead of just adding as expression which will result as a string.

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>         
  <input type="text" ng-model="one">
  <input type="text" ng-model="two">
  <input type="text" ng-model="three">
  <input type="text" ng-model="four">
   <br>{{one  * 1 + two  * 1 + three  * 1 + four  * 1}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Multiplying and string by `1` to convert it to integer is an unnecesarrily deceptive method .

Comment: @nicooga There are far better ways to do this requirement ! but according to OP requirement, this is the only way

Comment: @nicooga You can't use `parseInt()` inside curly braces so this is the best way to create this!